# How To Use Zip Code To Find Regions/Metros

Tags: zipcode, craigslist

Many classifieds sites request a user's zipcode to narrow content results to the user's region or metro area. (e.g. I type in `37803` and get `Knoxville, TN`, the appropriate metro region for Maryville, TN. Think Craigslist.) How does one go about getting such results with (U.S.) zip code only?

I'm assuming the answers will be some API's to query. I've found sites that will return an HTML page with the exact city, but I'm hoping to find something that A) will return JSON, XML or text data vs. HTML, and B) will return the nearest or encompassing metro.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, that ZIP code belongs to Maryville, TN.

You can try an API like LiveAddress. (Note: I used to work at SmartyStreets.)

The API calls are simple enough:

```
https://api.smartystreets.com/zipcode?zipcode=37803&auth-id=<id>&auth-token=<token>
```

Here's the response:

```
[
    {
        "input_index": 0,
        "city_states": [
            {
                "city": "Maryville",
                "state_abbreviation": "TN",
                "state": "Tennessee"
            }
        ],
        "zipcodes": [
            {
                "zipcode": "37803",
                "zipcode_type": "S",
                "county_fips": "47009",
                "county_name": "Blount",
                "latitude": 35.7082,
                "longitude": -83.974
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For low-volume usage, it's a free service.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's awesome. Do you have anything, though, that can grab Maryville's nearest metro (which would be Knoxville)? If I'm serving content for the Knoxville area, I would want anybody who punches in 37803 (or other surrounding zip codes) to get Knoxville results.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. It's not built-in to the API, no.

Comment: Thanks for the tool, though. I can certainly think of some projects to use that on.